# store a checkbox value and output result for user

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have a checkbox and I want to be able to have it so that it controls a variable construction, 0 being no construction, and 1 being construction. And outputs any current value so that the user can see whether construction is checked or not. I realize that check boxes do not post values that are 'not checked', and I have tried many things already. I am not sure where my logic is flawed.

```
<input name="construction" type="checkbox" id="construction" onChange="this.form.submit();" <?php if ($row_config['construction'] == 1) { echo ' checked'; } else { echo ' unchecked'; } ?>>

<?php
if ($_POST) {
    // 0 = off
    // 1 = on
    $constr = (isset($_POST['construction']) && $_POST['construction'] == "on") ? 1 : 0; 
    mysql_query("UPDATE config SET construction = '$constr'") or die(mysql_error());
    redirect('index.php');
}
?>
```

I think the problem is somewhere regarding the outputting the data to the user.

FIXED VERSION, thanks guys!

```
<?php
require('framework/ui_framework.php');
page_protect();

$config = mysql_query("SELECT construction FROM config") or die(mysql_error());
$row_config = mysql_fetch_assoc($config);

$isChecked = false;
$constr = 0;
if(isset($_POST['construction'])){
    if($_POST['construction']) {
        $isChecked = true;
        $constr = 1;
        mysql_query("UPDATE config SET construction = '".$constr."'") or die(mysql_error());
    }
} else {
    $isChecked = false;
    $constr = 0;
    mysql_query("UPDATE config SET construction = '".$constr."'") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>

<input name="construction" type="checkbox" id="construction" onChange="this.form.submit();" <?php if($isChecked) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> value="on">
```

Comment: Does your code block show two different pages stuck together? Or are you checking for $_POST['construction'] before the user has submitted the form? If it's the latter, that's the (or a) problem.

Comment: its all on the same page

Comment: Sorry, I asked the wrong question. Are you checking for the value of $_POST['construction'] before or after the user has hit the submit button on the form?

Comment: there is no submit button per-say, the checkbox has an onchange submit and the value is checked after submit. when i use a button instead of jquery or onchange the script works find as @palladium said. but apparently it doesnt process the value when i use on change. very odd. id rather not have a submit button but it seems to be the only way it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

and you have to check for variables using isset($varname)

```
<?php
  $isChecked = false;
  $constr = 0;
  if(isset($_POST['construction'])){
    if($_POST['construction'] == 'on'){
      $isChecked = true;
      $constr = 1;
    }      
    mysql_query("UPDATE config SET contruction = '$constr'") or die(mysql_error());

  }

?>

<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>

  </head>

  <body>
    <form action='test3.php' method='POST'>
      <input name="construction" type="checkbox" id="construction" onChange="this.form.submit()" <?php if($isChecked) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> />
      <?php

      ?>
    </form>     
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You dont need to echo checked or unchecked, as this code checks the box if it was checked.. if you still want to than add it to the php brackets after the input based on the $isChecked variable

Comment: this worked perfectly. although the other way worked as well, this is the best answer because i dont have to use a submit button! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You never set the value for your checkbox, so your logic `(isset($_POST['construction']) && $_POST['construction'] == "on")` fails when it checks `$_POST['construction'] == "on"`

If it's just a matter of seeing if the checkbox is checked or not, just use `isset()` and don't worry about checking the value.

Comment: Also, as @Palladium mentioned, `else echo 'unchecked'` is unnecessary.

Comment: made the changes you suggested. however it only works if for example i manually set the db value to 0. then click the checkbox then it sets the db value to 1. but if i click the checkbox again it doesnt set it to 0. thats my main problem

Answer (score 2):

You haven't actually given your checkbox a value. Judging from the PHP following, it would appear that you're missing `value="on"` from your list of attributes for your checkbox. Also, the `else echo 'unchecked'` in the checkbox setup is unnecessary.

Comment: i figured that as well but ive been trying everything . it only works if for example i manually set the db value to 0. then click the checkbox then it sets the db value to 1. but if i click the checkbox again it doesnt set it to 0.

Comment: @Alex If it's a matter of the checkbox not submitting when being unclicked, you can use `onclick()` instead of `onchange()`. Perhaps that will work better.

Comment: this is the exact problem, i have tried that. even doing it with jquery but it still doesnt uncheck the box / revert the checkbox back to 0 `<input name="construction" type="checkbox" id="construction" onClick="this.form.submit();" <?php if ($row_config['construction'] == 1) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>>`

Comment: @Alex Then try moving the PHP part after the checkbox to the top of the script. PHP runs in sequence - as it stands you're doing the query after the checkbox has already been set up as checked.

Comment: if i use a button it works. but it doesnt look good for the ui. and the php is at the top in my script. i just pasted it here in a diffrent sequence